# What does it mean for a column space to be a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I'm not sure how I would approach this problem. If i had a column that contained (1,6,1,1) it would satisfy the equation below , but I don't where to go on from here to construct the other 3 columns.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible.

This columnspace is of dimension $3$, which means $A$ contains $3$ pivots, and a row of $0$s at the bottom. This row of $0$s implies that
$$\operatorname{Col} A \subseteq \{(x_1, x_2, x_3, 0) : x_1, x_2, x_3 \in \Bbb{F}\}$$
(where $\Bbb{F}$ is the field you're working in; I'm guessing $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$). But, this is clearly not the case, as the vector you came up with demonstrates.

In general, the columnspace of an $n \times n$ RREF matrix must take the form
$$\operatorname{span}(e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_k)$$
where $e_i$ is the $i$th standard basis vector, and $0 \le k \le n$.

On the other hand, if you're given a subspace and told that it's *nullspace* of a RREF matrix, there is always a unique solution!

EDIT: In answer to the questions in the comments.

In general, checking whether a subspace matches the above form (i.e. is the columnpace of a RREF matrix) depends on how the subspace is presented. Is it an equation (or system of equations) like this? Is it the span of a list of vectors? Or is it something totally different?

No matter which form it comes in, try to concentrate on finding which standard basis vectors lie in the space (i.e. which ones satisfy the definition, whatever it is). In the $4 \times 4$ case, for example, first check whether $e_1 = (1, 0, 0, 0)$ satisfies the definition. In our example, we see that
$$1 + 2 \cdot 0 - 5 \cdot 0 - 8 \cdot 0 = 1 \neq 0,$$
hence $e_1$ is not in our proposed columnspace. The only way this is the case is if the columnspace is the span of the emptyset, i.e. is the space $\{(0, 0, 0, 0)\}$. This is clearly not the case; the proposed columnspace contains more than this vector.

Let's say that it did contain $e_1$. Then check $e_2$. If $e_2$ does not lie in this space, then the only candidate would be $\operatorname{span} (e_1)$. It should be a one-dimensional subspace! If you can find a vector in this space with a non-zero entry in anywhere else than the first coordinate, then this would mean there is no RREF matrix with this columnspace.

Keep trying standard basis vectors in order. Find the smallest $k$ such that $e_k$ does not lie in the space. Then prove or disprove that the proposed columnspace is equal to $\operatorname{span}(e_1, \ldots, e_{k-1})$.

As for how I computed the dimension of the subspace, my favourite method is using the rank-nullity theorem. Consider the linear transformation, from $\Bbb{F}^4$ to $\Bbb{F}$:
$$f(a, b, c, d) = a + 2b - 5c - 8d.$$
Note that $f$ is surjective (if it weren't, it would have a range of dimension less than $1$, which would make it the $0$ transformation). So, by the rank-nullity theorem,
$$\operatorname{null}(f) = \dim(\Bbb{F}^4) - \operatorname{rank}(f) = 4 - 1 = 3.$$
Finally, note that the nullspace of $f$ is precisely the proposed columnspace!

You can also just note that the proposed columnspace is not equal to all of $\Bbb{F}^4$ (e.g. $e_1$ is not in it). Therefore, it must be of dimension at most $3$ (possibly less), and thus must contain at least one $0$ row (possibly more), which yields the same result anyway.

Comment: how would I approach this if i wanted to construct a matrix to check

Comment: What do you want to check?

Comment: if its possible to create a matrix with conditions similar to this, how did you figure out that the dimension was 3

Comment: @SamuraiBale I've edited.